# Why my getName() method is not starting from the first row in my csv file?

Tags: java, file, csv

```
public int getRank(int auxYear, String auxName){
       //FileResource auxFr = new FileResource("/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv");
         String resourceName = "/Users/User/Desktop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv";
         File auxFile = new File(resourceName);
         if(auxFile.exists()){
         FileResource auxFr = new FileResource(auxFile);
       //FileResource auxFr = new FileResource();
         int auxRank = 0;
         for (CSVRecord auxRec : auxFr.getCSVParser(false)){
             if (auxRec.get(1).contains(auxGender)){
                auxRank += 1;
                String auxN = auxRec.get(0);
                if (auxRec.get(0).contains(auxName)){
                   return auxRank;
                }
             }
         }            
}
```

the getName method is reading another csv file and not staring from the first row, below the code :

```
 public String getName(int auxYear, int auxRank, String auxGender){
    ////FileResource auxFr = new FileResource("/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv");
        String resourceName = "/Users/User/Desktop/coursera/week4_babybirths/babybirths/testing/yob" + auxYear + "short.csv";
        File auxFile = new File(resourceName);
        if (auxFile.exists()){
        FileResource auxFr = new FileResource(auxFile);
        int auxCount = 0;
        for (CSVRecord auxRec : auxFr.getCSVParser()){
            String auxStr = auxRec.get(0);
            if (auxRec.get(1).contains(auxGender)){
                auxCount += 1;
                String auxStr1 = auxRec.get(0);
                if (auxCount == (auxRank-1)){
                    return auxRec.get(0);
                }
            }
        }               
    }
```

I use also :

```
public String yourNameInYear(String auxName, int auxYear, int auxNewYear, String auxGender){
    int auxRank = getRank(auxYear, auxName, auxGender);
    return getName(auxNewYear, auxRank, auxGender);
}

public void testYourNameInYear(){
    String auxName = yourNameInYear("Isabella", 2012, 2014, "F");
    System.out.println("Isabella" + " born in " + 2012 + " would be " + auxName + " in " + 2014);
}
```

by default `YourNameInYear` will call `getRank` this one will open the `yob2012short.csv` then after processing, `getName` will be called and open `yob2014short.csv`. I don't know why this one is not starting from the first row ?

Comment: For the record: there are other human beings on the receiving side of this utter mess you drop on us. Seriously : what the heck were you thinking looking at the edit preview and then hitting the submit button?

Comment: sorry is my first time human race thank you

Comment: There is an edit button to improve your question. You better hit that, and use the preview and the markdown language explanations. Dont try to be quick-witted, fix that **mess**.

Comment: We can't even fix it for you, as it is mostly code.

Comment: I tried to fix this by editing it, check for it, but please try to improve your writing skills,

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
       if (auxRec.get(1).contains(auxGender)){
            String auxStr1 = auxRec.get(0);
            if (auxCount == (auxRank-1)){
                return auxRec.get(0);
            }
       auxCount += 1;     
        }
```

as I gess `auxCaunt` must be your `current row` so if you increment it from `0` to `1` then you do call the getName with an `auxRank` equals to `0` (first row may be 0 not 1) so `0` is not equal to `1` so it will loop until `auxRank` equals `2`

Comment: Sorry, but answers that go "code only" have very limited usage. Please add at least some bit of explanation.

Comment: @GhostCat explanation added